# Objective-C Naming UILabel iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been wondering for quite a long time what to do with this.

Suppose I will be creating an UILabel, this label will contain a name.
So without giving it much of thought, I will name this UILabel |name|.

Then I will have an NSString which will hold the actual string of the name.
So I think naming the string |name| would be more appropriate right?

But what would I name the UILabel then?

I thought about naming it labelName.

But this is hungarian notation which is highly discouraged?

This is a dead end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objective-C is a verbose language. It's common to include the type of variables and parameters  when naming them.

```
UILabel *nameLabel = ...
NSString *name = ...
```

In case of primitive values (or even NSStrings and NSNumbers) usually the type is omitted.

Comment: super faster than me...almost similar :)

Comment: Finally I found some who think the same as me. I was just told, dont include the type in the name. I thought about doing something like "labelName", to make the code look cleaner when I have a lot of UILabels(So they will be aligned). But then I stopped that habit too.

Comment: If I saw a variable called `labelName` I would assume it's a string that stores the name of a label. I recommend `nameLabel`.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you get this kind of situation, think, rethink and change the names.

In your case, you can use :

```
UILabel *nameLabel;
NSString *name; //*nameString; // *nameValue;
```

You can suffix the type *(although not a good practice, but exceptions are there*) as in the following example.

`nameArray` is not good name it should be `names`

```
NSArray *names; // instead of nameArray
```

Comment: Why is it not good practice? It's quite common, even in Apple's APIs.

Comment: @DrummerB: suffixing the type means, `NSArray *nameArray` instead of `names`.

Comment: Of course, but in this case it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @DrummerB: Thats why I said exceptions ;)

Comment: Getting kind of confused here. The answer is "nameArray is not good name it should be names". But then in the code it recommends nameArray?

Comment: i dint recommended :p. wait i will make it clear

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your main problem is that your model is leaking into the view. Your label (clearly a view) should preferably not know anything about the model it is presenting.

Take for example a look at `UITableViewCell`. It has outlets called

- `textLabel`
- `detailTextLabel`
- `imageView`

These can be used to present almost any kind of model data that has some main text and optionally an image and/or more text to present.

You may also note that in these examples UIKit suffixes the variable with the type (adding `Label` at the end of the label). The same things applies for the `backgroundColor` property on UIView.

Comment: Not necessarily. If he is implementing a controller, wouldn't he have a view (label) and a model (string)?